# taking an average of every 3 points in an array and saving new values into a new array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I am trying to take an average of every 3 points in an array and output the new values into a new array. However something in my code must be wrong as I keep getting the same error message.

Here is my code:

```
# y average values

avgy = [0]*(len(y1)//3)

for i in range (0, len(y1)-2):
    if (3*(1+i)<=len(y1)):
        avgy[i] = ( y1[3*i+1] + y1[3*i+2] y1[3*i])/3


# x average values

avgx = [0]*(len(x1)//3)

for i in range (0, len(x1)-2):
    if (3*(1+i)<=len(x1)):
        avgx[i] = ( x1[3*i+1] + x1[3*i+2] x1[3*i])/3
```

The error message:

```
 File "<ipython-input-12-bebc7029e3d1>", line 16
    avgy[i] = ( y1[3*i+1] + y1[3*i+2] y1[3*i])/3
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks in advance,
Oliver

Comment: You're missing plus signs `+`. In Python, numbers don't add by simply being next to each other. :P

Comment: thank you for spotting the typo!

Comment: So, for [1,2,3,4,5,6] you want [average([1,2,3]), average([4,5,6])]?

Comment: no i was looking for: ([1,2,3,4,5,6])  average of every three data points i.e. ([2,5])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is missing + before y1[3*i])/3 and x1[3*i])/3

```
# y average values

avgy = [0]*(len(y1)//3)

for i in range (0, len(y1)-2):
    if (3*(1+i)<=len(y1)):
        avgy[i] = ( y1[3*i+1] + y1[3*i+2] + y1[3*i])/3


# x average values

avgx = [0]*(len(x1)//3)

for i in range (0, len(x1)-2):
    if (3*(1+i)<=len(x1)):
        avgx[i] = ( x1[3*i+1] + x1[3*i+2] + x1[3*i])/3
```